# Symbolication of crash log not happening

Tags: ios, xcode5, crash-reports

I have the dSYM file and original archive of an application that users are having crashes with.

When opening the crash file in Xcode, there is no symbolization. I cannot seem to figure out why?

Here is the crash report incase it contains any clues:

```
Incident Identifier: 59F6672E-E162-4ACA-9729-84DAAE5A25AB
CrashReporter Key:   53aabaae4c95151479ce310333d5f12d2407ecfe
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             Tweetly [3202]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/51E8C5A0-DEE5-4E1C-A1C0-2CE60456F074/Tweetly.app/Tweetly
Identifier:          com.indeebox.tweetly
Version:             1.01 (1.01)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-12-08 19:54:31.647 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2ecc5e7e 0x390226c2 0x2ecc97b2 0x2ecc80aa 0x2ec16dc4 0x874d0 0x3157c310 0x315246c8 0x31523eec 0x3144a34e 0x310d093e 0x310cc162 0x310cbff4 0x310cba08 0x310cb81a 0x310c5548 0x2ec90f64 0x2ec8e8f2 0x2ec8ec3e 0x2ebf946c 0x2ebf924e 0x339332e6 0x314ae840 0xa9322 0x3951bab2)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d21fc 0x395bf000 + 78332
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39639a4e 0x39636000 + 14926
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39583028 0x39539000 + 303144
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389d198a 0x389d1000 + 2442
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389ea6e2 0x389d1000 + 104162
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39022936 0x3901a000 + 35126
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389e81b0 0x389d1000 + 94640
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389e7d12 0x389d1000 + 93458
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3902280a 0x3901a000 + 34826
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2ebf94e2 0x2ebf1000 + 34018
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2ebf924e 0x2ebf1000 + 33358
11  GraphicsServices                0x339332e6 0x3392c000 + 29414
12  UIKit                           0x314ae840 0x3143f000 + 456768
13  Tweetly                         0x000a9322 0x6c000 + 250658
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3951bab4 0x3951a000 + 6836

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395bf838 0x395bf000 + 2104
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3950e0d0 0x39506000 + 32976
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3950861e 0x39506000 + 9758

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2c7c 0x395bf000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636e06 0x39636000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636cc0 0x39636000 + 3264

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2c7c 0x395bf000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636e06 0x39636000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636cc0 0x39636000 + 3264

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2c7c 0x395bf000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636e06 0x39636000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636cc0 0x39636000 + 3264

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395bfa84 0x395bf000 + 2692
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395bf87c 0x395bf000 + 2172
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec90554 0x2ebf1000 + 652628
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec8ec74 0x2ebf1000 + 646260
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2ebf946c 0x2ebf1000 + 33900
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2ebf924e 0x2ebf1000 + 33358
6   Foundation                      0x2f6344bc 0x2f5dc000 + 361660
7   Foundation                      0x2f6a9c32 0x2f5dc000 + 842802
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39638c5a 0x39636000 + 11354
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39638bca 0x39636000 + 11210
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636ccc 0x39636000 + 3276

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2c7c 0x395bf000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636e06 0x39636000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636cc0 0x39636000 + 3264

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2c7c 0x395bf000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636e06 0x39636000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636cc0 0x39636000 + 3264

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2440 0x395bf000 + 78912
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec94456 0x2ebf1000 + 668758
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39638c5a 0x39636000 + 11354
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39638bca 0x39636000 + 11210
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636ccc 0x39636000 + 3276

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395d2c7c 0x395bf000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636e06 0x39636000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39636cc0 0x39636000 + 3264

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b3ff18c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d975a4
    r8: 0x165c2170    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x31a31122     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d97598      lr: 0x39639a53      pc: 0x395d21fc
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x6c000 - 0x207fff Tweetly armv7s  <fdd33418abc531bd8ac5b90ff517b6fb> /var/mobile/Applications/51E8C5A0-DEE5-4E1C-A1C0-2CE60456F074/Tweetly.app/Tweetly
0x2be18000 - 0x2be3bfff dyld armv7s  <fd7cb81f388f39cbac4f71338b669c24> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2db55000 - 0x2dc56fff AVFoundation armv7s  <759b362f09e53f37a2ec82372a95d1de> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
```

The end had a bunch more but it wouldn't fit. Any idea why it isn't working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must select Devices and at the top device logs. Drag and drop the CRASH files here and then press the re-symbolicate button at the bottom. Works like a charm.